# Is there any alternate method for CoordinatorLayout. onNestedScroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

CoordinatorLayout. onNestedScroll method is supported for the api level>21. So, I have to skip calling this method in the code if the device api level is <21. For example(`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            binding.layoutCoordination.onNestedScroll(binding.recyclerView, 0, 1000, 0, 0);
        }`) . But, instead of skipping the method call, is there any other way?

Comment: Are you sure that it isnt supported on API device<21?   It is in the support design library.

Comment: Yeah I am sure it isn't supported on API device<21.